# Convert PDF files to decimal array before sending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, pdf

I have a form that I need to send its contents using json and curl to an API.
It all works fine, until I get to the files.

The form receives from the user between 1 to 4 PDF files, which I need to send as a decimal array.

I don't have much experience with this kind of tasks but I've looked around and the best I could get is converting the file in JS to Base64 which is converted to Base16 and sent to the server side using ajax to be converted to decimal and sent.

It held as long as I used small files of no more than few hundred KB, but when tried larger files - it seems that the size of the package to be sent is like 4 times the size of the original files... I guess there's something to do with the "over conversion" which adds to the file size in each conversion.

This is my JS for converting the file from the input field to comma separated Base16 string

```
$('.file-field').on('change', function(e) {
  var input_id = $(this).attr('id')
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var filename = file.name;
  var filetype = file.type;
  var filesize = file.size;
  var data = {
      "filename": filename,
      "filetype": filetype,
      "filesize": filesize
  };
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
      data.file_base64 = e.target.result.split(/,/)[1];
      var file_base16 = base64ToBase16(data.file_base64);
      var file_base16CS = file_base16.replace(/.{2}/g, '$&,');
      $("#"+input_id+"_array").val(file_base16CS).attr({
          "filename": data.filename,
          "filetype": data.filetype,
          "filesize": data.filesize,
      });

  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
```

And this is on the PHP:

```
$thefile = $dataArray["thefile"];
if($thefile['file'] != 0) {
    $file_hex_array = explode(",", $thefile['file']);
    $file_dec_array = array();
    foreach($file_hex_array as $file_hex) {
       $file_dec_array[] = hexdec($file_hex);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the process more simple and handle larger files without making them huge?